# Remove content of a list out of other list

Tags: python, list

I have some code that creates a list with numbers, from 1 to 407. What I want to do it to take the numbers of the "ultimate" and "super_rare" list out of the "common" list. How can I do that? This is the general code I have.

```
import random

def common(x):
    list = []
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        list.append(i)
    return (list)

cid = common(407)


ultimate = [404, 200, 212, 15, 329, 214, 406, 259, 126, 160, 343, 180, 169, 297, 226, 305, 250, 373, 142, 357, 181, 113, 149, 399, 287, 341, 37, 284, 41, 328, 400, 217, 253, 204, 290, 18, 174, 36, 310, 303, 6, 108, 47, 298, 130]

super_rare = [183, 349, 134, 69, 103, 342, 83, 380, 93, 56, 86, 95, 147, 161, 403, 197, 215, 312, 375, 359, 263, 221, 340, 102, 153, 234, 54, 7, 238, 193, 90, 367, 197, 397, 33, 366, 334, 222, 394, 371, 313, 83, 276, 35, 351, 83, 347, 170, 57, 201, 137, 188, 179, 170, 65, 107, 234, 48, 2, 85, 74, 221, 23, 171, 101, 377, 63, 248, 102, 272, 129, 276, 86, 88, 51, 197, 248, 202, 244, 153, 138, 101, 330, 68, 368, 292, 340, 315, 185, 219, 381, 89, 274, 175, 385, 19, 257, 313, 191, 211]


def new_list(cid, ultimate):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(cid)):
        new_list.append(cid[i])

    for i in range(len(ultimate)):
        new_list.remove(ultimate[i])
    return (new_list)

#print (new_list(cid, ultimate))
cid_mod0 = new_list(cid, ultimate)
cid_mod1 = new_list(cid_mod0, super_rare)

print (cid_mod0)
```

Most of the prints and whatnot are just tries to see if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using sets for this. You can check if an item is in a set in constant time. For example:

```
import random

def common(x):
   return list(range(1, x + 1))

cid = common(407)

ultimate = { 404, 200, ... }
super_rare = { 183, 349, ... }

def list_difference(l, s):
  return [ elem for elem in l if elem not in s ]

cid_mod0 = list_difference(cid, ultimate)
cid_mod1 = list_difference(cid_mod0, super_rare)
```

If you don't care about the order of your resulting list you can use a set for that as well for a bit more convenience:

```
import random

def common(x):
   return list(range(1, x + 1))

cid = set(common(407))

ultimate = { 404, 200, ... }
super_rare = { 183, 349, ... }

cid_mod0 = cid - ultimate
cid_mod1 = cid_mod0 - super_rare
```

Comment: I tried that last one but it says "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'.

Comment: Did you try exactly as it is now? I had a little typo in there sorry.

Comment: I tried it with the new version and the same error appears :/

Comment: Strange, I ran this and it worked for me. did you wrap `cid` in `set` and change `ultimate` and `super_rare` to curly braces? You can wrap them in `set` as well.

Comment: The curly braces were missing, now it's running perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this loop to remove the elements out of common that are in the `super_rare` and `ultimate` lists:

```
for x, cnum in enumerate(cid):
    if cnum in ultimate or cnum in super_rare:
        del cid[x]
print(cid)
```

The loop assumes you have a list named `cid` that is already established.

Comment: I tried that one, but it says " 'function' object is not iterable" on "for x, cnum in enumerate(common): "

Comment: Try it now with the new edits. I didn't see your list was called `cid`.

Comment: It doesn't give an error anymore but when I printed it, it just gave me a loop printing the list

Comment: Outside of the loop, `print(cid)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create your target list that includes all the numbers from the target range, but without those numbers from `ultimate` and `super_rare` list, by list comprehension:

```
my_filtered_list = [i for i in range(1, 408) if i not in ultimate and i not in super_rare]
print(my_filtered_list)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a beginner at this, I don't know how and where should I write that xD

Comment: I edited my answer.  That list contain all the numbers you need.

Answer (score 0):

Make a [union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) set of both sets of numbers you want to exclude.

```
>>> su = set(ultimate) | set(super_rare)
```

Then [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) the input list based on whether the value is not present in the set.

```
>>> list(filter(lambda i: i not in su, cid))
[1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 49, 50, 52, 53, 55, 58, 59, 
 60, 61, 62, 64, 66, 67, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 84, 87, 
 91, 92, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 104, 105, 106, 109, 110, 111, 112, 114, 115, 
 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 127, 128, 131, 132, 133, 135, 
 136, 139, 140, 141, 143, 144, 145, 146, 148, 150, 151, 152, 154, 155, 156, 157, 
 158, 159, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 172, 173, 176, 177, 178, 182, 184, 
 186, 187, 189, 190, 192, 194, 195, 196, 198, 199, 203, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 
 210, 213, 216, 218, 220, 223, 224, 225, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 235, 
 236, 237, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 245, 246, 247, 249, 251, 252, 254, 255, 256, 
 258, 260, 261, 262, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 273, 275, 277, 278, 
 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 285, 286, 288, 289, 291, 293, 294, 295, 296, 299, 300, 
 301, 302, 304, 306, 307, 308, 309, 311, 314, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 
 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 331, 332, 333, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 344, 345, 346, 
 348, 350, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 358, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 369, 370, 
 372, 374, 376, 378, 379, 382, 383, 384, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 
 395, 396, 398, 401, 402, 405, 407]
```

If you don't want to use filter, just use a list comprehension.

```
>>> [v for v in cid if v not in su]
```

You could also do the whole thing with sets like

```
>>> list(set(cid) - (set(ultimate) | set(super_rare)))
```

Others have suggested this already (I take no credit). I'm not sure how guaranteed it is to come back in the right order. Seems to be ok on my py2 and py3, but doing the last step as a list will give you the order absolutely guaranteed (not as an implementation detail) and wont need converting back to a list as a final step.

If you want to see the changes in the original list, you can just assign back to the original variable.

```
cid = [v for v in cid if v not in su]
```

This is assigning a different list to the same variable though, so other holders of references to that list won't see the changes. You can call `id(cid)` before and after the assignment to see that its a different list.

If you wanted to assign back to the exact same list instance you can use

```
cid[:] = [v for v in cid if v not in su]
```

and the id will remain the same.

Comment: It didn't give me an error! But I printed the original cid list and it prints all the numbers from 0 to 407.

Comment: This creates a new list. The original is not changed. So you wanted to change the original list?

Comment: Yes, I want the original list to stop having those numbers.

Comment: Ok well just assign back to `cid`. `cid = [v for v in cid if v not in su]`. `cid` will point to a new list in this case though. A way to assign back to the original list is to use `cid[:] = [v for v in cid if v not in su]`.

Comment: @curious was wondering if you made any progress on your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the original order for `cid`, you could try to use [OrderDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to convert cid as an `ordered dict` object, and then remove keys that you want, the code would be something like:

```
from random import choices, seed
from collections import OrderedDict

seed(123)

ultimate = [404, 200, 212, 15, 329, 214, 406, 259, 126, 160, 343, 180, 169, 297, 226, 305, 250, 373, 142, 357, 181, 113, 149, 399, 287, 341, 37, 284, 41, 328, 400, 217, 253, 204, 290, 18, 174, 36, 310, 303, 6, 108, 47, 298, 130]
super_rare = [183, 349, 134, 69, 103, 342, 83, 380, 93, 56, 86, 95, 147, 161, 403, 197, 215, 312, 375, 359, 263, 221, 340, 102, 153, 234, 54, 7, 238, 193, 90, 367, 197, 397, 33, 366, 334, 222, 394, 371, 313, 83, 276, 35, 351, 83, 347, 170, 57, 201, 137, 188, 179, 170, 65, 107, 234, 48, 2, 85, 74, 221, 23, 171, 101, 377, 63, 248, 102, 272, 129, 276, 86, 88, 51, 197, 248, 202, 244, 153, 138, 101, 330, 68, 368, 292, 340, 315, 185, 219, 381, 89, 274, 175, 385, 19, 257, 313, 191, 211]

cid = OrderedDict.fromkeys(choices(range(407), k=407))
_ = map(cid.pop, set(ultimate + super_rare))

result = cid.keys()
```

If you don't need the original order, you could try to convert cid as a `dict`, it's superfast to remove key from a hashmap, the code would be something like:

```
cid = dict.fromkeys(range(407))
_ = map(cid.pop, set(ultimate + super_rare))

result = cid.keys()
```

Apart from the dictionary method, you can also try to convert everything into a `set` variable like the following:

```
result = set(range(407)) - set(ultimate) - set(super_rare)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I ended up with this:
`
return (list(range(1, x+1)))

cid = set(common(407))
cid_mod0 = cid - ultimate
cid_mod1 = cid_mod0 - super_rare
`
(there's some code missing but it isn't very important) and I changed the vars to dictionaries. Now I'm trying to call .random.choice() on cid_mod1 but it says, on that line, " 'set' object is not subscriptable. Since you talked about sets, I was hoping you could help me.

Comment: Hi @curious , random.choice() is trying to create some random data, you don't have to use that if unnecessary, maybe you can try to convert that set object to a list object, e.g. cid_mod1 = list(set( YOUR-OBJECT )).